# Fixing "CS8762: Parameter must have a non-null value when exiting with 'true'."

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

How do I tell the compiler that my `out` variable is assigned the moment I am returning with true?

```
private static bool Resolve(IEnumerable<Type> testClasses, string requestedTestClass, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Type? resolvedTestClass)
{
  resolvedTestClass = null;
  List<Type> matches = new();
  List<string> options = new();

  // determine matches
  foreach(var testClass in testClasses)
  {
    options.Add($"{testClass.Name} from {testClass.Namespace}");
    if (testClass.Name.StartsWith(requestedTestClass))
    {
      matches.Add(testClass);

      // remember the first match
      if (matches.Count == 1)
      {
        resolvedTestClass = testClass;
      }
    }
  }

  if (matches.Count == 1)
  {
    return true;
  }

  // outputting here all matches and all options if more than one match was found

  return false;
}
```

The compiler says that the parameter `resolvedTestClass` must have a non-null value when exiting with 'true'. Since it's the same condition it is true, but the compiler just cannot know.

I admit there are better ways to implement the functionality, so let's take this just as an example and focus on the central question which is: Is there a way to tell the compiler (eg. with placing some attribute(s) somewhere) that "all is alright"?

Comment: Why not return from within the loop, as soon as you've set `resolvedTestClass`? Why loop over the other entries in `testClasses`?

Comment: I don't see the point for that `out` parameter at all. You're returning `Type?` so either the returned has a value or it's null. Also, unless there's more code, that would make more sense with a LINQ query

Comment: @JonSkeet I do so because I want to collect all "options" the user would have and output them together with the matches if more than one match was found.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I then I check at all call sites for the return value to be != null instead of a clean boolean check? That is a violation of DRY in my optinion.

Comment: So when you say "Since it's the same condition it is true" you don't actually mean it's the same condition - you mean that it will have been set at least once. I would suggest setting `resolvedTestClass = matches[0];` before returning `true`, and removing the assignment within the `if` condition.

Comment: @JonSkeet In terms of code design I agree with you. Your proposed implementation is better. But if we take this as an example: Is there a way to tell the compiler (eg. with placing some attribute(s) somewhere) that "all is alright"? I have the notion that this is not the case.

Comment: Side note: that's funny you mention DRY but yet manually write out code for `.Where`... I'm afraid that none of approaches that could be suggested would satisfy your fashion sense. And question probably will have to be closed as "opinion based" due to that.

Comment: @David: You *may* be able to write `resolvedTestClass = resolvedTestClass!;`. Or you could just suppress the warning in this case, probably.

Comment: How about `return resolvedTestClass != null` in the if? Are you making a sort of "forgiving Single" whereby instead of throwing an exception when "sequence contains more than one matching element" you "sequence contains more than one matching element, here's the first"? (You can quit the loop when count == 2?)

Comment: @CaiusJard `if (matches.Count == 1) { return resolvedTestClass != null; }` solves the issue. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Minimally, it looks like you can do away with the lists too..

```
    private static bool Resolve(IEnumerable<Type> testClasses, string requestedTestClass, [NotNullWhen(true)] out Type? resolvedTestClass)
    {
      resolvedTestClass = null;
      bool multiple = false;

      // determine matches
      foreach(var testClass in testClasses)
      {
        if (testClass.Name.StartsWith(requestedTestClass))
        {
          multiple = (resolvedTestClass != null); //have we already seen a match?
          if(multiple) break;                     //don't need to check any more to know we have multiple
          resolvedTestClass = testClass;          //only set once; the first time
        }
      }

      return !multiple && resolvedTestClass != null;
    }
```

<sub>It doesn't actually complain if you remove the `&& resolvedTestClass != null`, but...</sub>